Why is TCP Header -> WINDOW being set to ZERO?
I have a snippet below which I found, and is a part of a code to create and send raw packet, which works by the way. This snippet is part of a code that sends a SYN packet.
However, the code sets the tcph-> window to htonl(65535). The window is only 16 bits, and after the htonl call, it actually gets assigned 0x0000. I don't get why not just set 0 directly. Also, what is the significance of setting the Window to 0 ? From what I understand, window, when set to 0, signifies that its buffer is already full and so will signal the other end to pause sending messages first.
But as I mentioned, this sets a SYN packet and would expect something in return (so should not ask the other end to stop sending ?)
void setup_tcp_header(struct tcphdr *tcph)
{
    tcph->source = htons(src_port);                 // SOURCE PORT
    tcph->dest = htons(dst_port);                   // TARGET PORT

    tcph->seq = random();
    tcph->ack_seq = 0;
    tcph->res2 = 0;
    tcph->doff = 5;
    tcph->syn = 1;



    tcph->window = htonl(65535);  // 0x FFFF 0000 but window is uint16_t so only gets the 00 00 
                                  // LSBs


    tcph->check = 0;
    tcph->urg_ptr = 0;
}


Verified with WS and indeed Window is set to 0:


Note: the hton? functions take unsigned integers, so htons is enough to eat 65535 without any integer promotions and truncation like what's kicking you in the face.

Anyway, I think this is the result of someone being ignorant, or too smart for their own britches, and not for any reason that's actually smart.

@user4581301 Yes, indeed. And actually, that is what I would like to get clarification with. Why bother calling htonl when it knows that the result will be truncated to 0 anyway? Why not just set it to 0 ?

It won't always be chopped to zero. Depending on the endian you could get 0xFFFF back out again.

@user4581301 In that regards, with my PC using Little Endian thereby setting window=0, will the remote end still be able to send me back something despite window flag telling it not to ?
